# What is a page in 8051 microprocessor?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

https://www.hobbyprojects.com/8051_tutorial/acall_absolute_call.html

I was learning about acall on the above website, but then came across the term page. What exactly is a page?

Comment: Try expanding your google search from "page", to "memory page".

Comment: The 8051 micro can only address 64K of memory.  In simple terms, f you need more an output pin can be used to connect another 64K of memory, another "bank" or page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, and in this context, the whole 11-bit address area that is accessible with the ACALL instruction is divided to eight areas called pages that are 256 bytes each.

As the ACALL opcode follows only a single byte which defines the 8 least significant bits of the address, there needs to be 8 different ACALL opcodes that define the high 3 bits - the page.

Comment: I think you mean "eight" different opcodes to provide the upper three bits. Or else just one opcode with an assembler option to specify the upper three bits into the opcode.

Comment: The ACALL opcode will be followed by a byte containing the 8 least significant bits of the destination address.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo